# ImportError: cannot import name 'AutoModelWithLMHead' from 'transformers'

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

This is literally all the code that I am trying to run:

```
from transformers import AutoModelWithLMHead, AutoTokenizer
import torch

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-small")
model = AutoModelWithLMHead.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-small")
```

I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-aad2e7a08a74> in <module>
----> 1 from transformers import AutoModelWithLMHead, AutoTokenizer
      2 import torch
      3 
      4 tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-small")
      5 model = AutoModelWithLMHead.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-small")

ImportError: cannot import name 'AutoModelWithLMHead' from 'transformers' (c:\python38\lib\site-packages\transformers\__init__.py)
```

What do I do about it?

Comment: Have you tried importing anything else from the transformers library?

Comment: What version of transformers are you using?

Comment: @cronoik I use the latest one. transformers-3.0.2

Comment: @A.T.B importing AutoTokenizer works just fine...

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please run `import transformers` and `transformers.__version__` to make sure that you are really working with `3.0.2`. How have you installed it?

Comment: @cronoik Solved it!

Comment: @cronoik it says '3.0.2' btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it! Apperantly AutoModelWithLMHead is removed on my version.

Now you need to use `AutoModelForCausalLM` for causal language models, `AutoModelForMaskedLM` for masked language models and `AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM` for encoder-decoder models.

So in my case code looks like this:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
import torch

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-small")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-small")
```