# Transformer: cannot import name 'AutoModelWithLMHead' from 'transformers'

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I was referring to this answer from stackoverflow but I can't get any leads regarding my problem: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141267/importerror-cannot-import-name-automodelwithlmhead-from-transformers][1]

This is the code that I ran:

```
import transformers
from transformers import AutoModelWithLMHead
```

Results:

```
cannot import name 'AutoModelWithLMHead' from 'transformers' (/Users/xev/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/__init__.py)
```

My transformer version is '3.0.2'.
My import for AutoTokenizer is fine.

Would appreciate if there's anyone who can help regarding the Transformers package!
[1]: [ImportError: cannot import name 'AutoModelWithLMHead' from 'transformers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141267/importerror-cannot-import-name-automodelwithlmhead-from-transformers)

Answer (score 8):

just make sure you installed the transformers using its official git link

```
pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
```

and not by using pypi

```
pip install transformers
```

coz there are few sub-libraries such as `TFLayoutLMForSequenceClassification`
missing in pypi transformers version

Answer (score 0):

Please try,

```
from transformers.modeling_auto import AutoModelWithLMHead
```